# Deconvolution in Python in 2D

Tags: noise, python, fourier, deconvolution, 2d

Referring to [this topic](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8287/deconvolution-in-python), I am interested in a deconvolution using Python.

However, unlike the linked topic above, I want to deconvolve a 2D image. The scipy.signal.deconvolve function unfortunately does not support 2D deconvolution.

This amounts to solving the following equation for *f*, when *h* is observed, *n* is the added noise and *g* is the convolution kernel, and all are 2d arrays:

*f* * *g* + *n* = *h*

My first question is therefore: **How can I perform a 2D deconvolution in Python?**

The most obvious option would be, for a known function *g*, to transform to Fourier space and divide *h* by *g*. I have read however that this is merely good for illustration purposes and fairly inaccurate for science purposes.

**So, what would be the cleanest, most accurate way of performing the deconvolution?**

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  I'd suggest implementing the 2D FFT-based approach, so you can see the problems and have something to compare other approaches with.  [This page](http://nbarbey.github.io/linear_operators/exemples/quadratic_deconvolution.html)  has a `python` package that may do something a little better. YMMV. I've not used that particular package before.

Answer (score 1):

Erik Hom has developped the [Adaptive Image Deconvolution Algorithm (AIDA)](https://code.google.com/p/aida-deconvolution/) in Python. Looking at this code may help you a lot develop your own code.

High-quality deconvolution is still a quite open problem. Dividing $h$ by $g$ in the Fourier domain might cause noise explosion, if $g$ possesses a limited spectrum. The most accurate way depends:

- on the knowledge of the kernel: is it constant, perfectly known ([standard Wiener deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution)), approximately known ([myopic deconvolution](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18285917)), unknown ([blind deconvolution](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.5465)),
- on the nature of the noise (Gaussian, Poisson, impulsive),
- on the properties of the class of images you are looking at (sparse, positive, bounded, compressible).

From my recent experience in signal deconvolution, transforming the image with a sparsifying transform, and constraining sparsity in the process may help a lot.